# Missed scrolls in Gedit and nautilus

Tags: virtualbox, scrolling, gnome3, nautilus, gedit

After I type anything in GEdit, it ignores the next 6 ticks of my scrollwheel in a direction. If I scroll 6 times up, it will then let me scroll up, but not down. To scroll down I will have to scroll 6 times down before it will let me, even though I had already scrolled 6 times up.

I'm running debian testing x64 under virtualbox.

This issue occurs in GEdit and nautilus.

How do I fix this behavior?